# Cannot get result from tQuery after success connected to SQL Server 2019 Express from my old Delphi 7 (using BDE and SQL Server as Driver Name)

Tags: odbc, delphi-7, sql-server-express, bde, tquery

I'm trying to access into a database in SQL Server 2019 Express from my old Delphi 7 project that still using BDE and SQL Server as Driver name (for migration only). With the db1 (`tDatabase`) setting like this:

```
DATABASE NAME=master
USER NAME=sa
ODBC DSN=base6280 *// (that I've created first)*
OPEN MODE=READ/WRITE
PASSWORD=abc
```

But after connecting to `MASTER` database, when I ran this query (`tQuery`):

```
cbDBname.Items.Clear;

Q := TQuery.Create(nil);
try
  Q.DataBaseName := 'MASTER';

  Q.SQL.Text := ' SELECT NAME as DBxxx 
                  FROM MASTER.DBO.SYSDATABASES  
                  ORDER BY Name DESC ';
  Q.Open;
  while not Q.Eof do
  begin
     cbDBname.Items.Add(Q.FieldByName('DBxxx').AsString);
     Q.Next;
  end;
```

I get an error :

[image]

Can somebody here help me to figure out? How to handle this error?

Thanks for your attention and any response (beside bde has been depreciated) is much more expected.

Comment: sorry, the error message was :
.exe raised exception class EDatabaseError with message 'Field 'DBxxx' not found'. Process stopped.
(  at line : cbDBname.Items.Add(Q.FieldByName('DBxxx').AsString);  )

Comment: thanks @marc_s for your revision, sorry my english is poor

Comment: well guys, I have figured out... 
the problem is BDE not support SYSNAME data type, so I have to change the query to be like this :

  Q.SQL.Text := ' SELECT CAST(NAME as varchar(128)) as DBxxx 
                  FROM SYS.DATABASES  
                  ORDER BY Name DESC ';
  Q.Open;

done... it worked, thanks

Comment: Honestly, BDE was deprecated almost 20 years ago and Delphi 7 has well over 15 years... it's a miracle (or the proof Delphi is a great tool) that this works ;-)